# How to make `adb reboot` work like `/system/bin/reboot`?

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, custom-roms, linux, shell

I have a problem with my device. When I do `adb reboot` then it stuck on boot in a loop.

But, when I do `adb shell` and then `reboot`, it works fine.

I searched over the internet and understand that both have different behavior:

- `adb reboot` works like you plug the phone battery out. Means, it will not close any application, not show any pretty Restarting splash screen.
- `adb shell` `reboot` uses `/system/bin/reboot` executable and it does a soft reboot with closing opened application, showing the splash screen, etc..

To verify that `adb shell` `reboot` execute `/system/bin/reboot`, I have moved the `/system/bin/reboot` to another place and as expected the `reboot` command not working anymore so I put it back after confirmation.

I want `adb reboot` to use `/system/bin/reboot` executable.

**I want to do it from within the Android device that makes it a general solution for all users of the device. I know I can execute `adb shell reboot` but other users will not do this.**

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: i am afraid you are looking for a solution on device, not for pc?

Comment: You are right that I am looking for a solution for the device.

Comment: Both `adb reboot` and `/system/bin/reboot` do the same thing i.e. set `sys.powerctl` property to `reboot` (with optional arguments), which you can do manually too. Both should do a graceful shutdown/reboot. Not sure if the behavior was different with old `adb` binaries.

Answer (score 2):

Write a script in your PC, look for 'reboot' argument, and execute your own command instead.

I do not know how a Window's compatible script would look like, but this is how a simple bash script would look like.

```
#!/bin/bash
ADB="PATH_TO_RENAMED_ADB_BINARY"

if [[ "$1" == "reboot" ]] && [[ -z ${2} ]]; then         # $1 is the first argument received by adb
    "$ADB" shell '/system/bin/reboot'    
else
    "$ADB" "$@"                            # $@ contains all the arguments received by adb
fi
```

Save the script as `adb`, give executable permission to it, rename adb binary with the name `adb_orig`, and then save this script as `adb` where adb is originally located.

Comment: I need a general solution. This will require me to place this script into the machine of a person who will be going to use this device. This is not possible for me. So, I want to do it from an Android device. Is it possible to write such script in the Android?

Comment: Hey, if I will use your script at `./system/bin/adbd` and rename old `adbd` to `orig_adbd` and edit the script with ADB="orig_adbd". Is it will work?

Comment: You would need to rebuild the adb where in the source code reboot command would point to your choice of binary. In any case, a universal solution cannot exist. You would either have to place a shell script in the PC or a specially crafted adb binary. Neither would qualify as a universal solution.

Comment: Or I can write my own daemon which will use existing `adbd` daemon for other commands. But this also needs existing daemon entry in init script to be deleted or replaced the path with a new daemon. This may also need some additional SELinux policies.

Comment: it is maybe easier to put a sticker on the back "warning: don't use adb reboot"

Comment: @VatishSharma the adb binary I've asked to rename is the adb client, simply named as adb. I do not know how to interact with adbd. You can try and experiment and post an answer. :)

Comment: Actually, there is one more problem that on clicking "Restart" from Android UI, the same thing happens. So, I doubt internally they are calling `adb reboot` not `adb shell reboot`. That's another reason of fixing it from the android side.

Comment: `adbd` is not a simple executable that can run `adbd reboot` but it is a kind of socket programming that listens for the commands sent by adb server. I think this needs to find `adbd` source code and inject the `system/bin/reboot` there.

Comment: Thanks for giving suggestions :)

Comment: @VatishSharma When you press on Restart button in the device, this is how it is initiated. You can follow the trail in the source code. See  [What's the best way to restart Android via command line (remotely)?](//android.stackexchange.com/a/139139) and [How can I shutdown my Android phone using an adb command?](//android.stackexchange.com/a/138057)

Comment: `adb shell su -c 'svc power reboot'` works fine. Is it means the device manufacture has implemented the restart functionality wrongly with executing `adb reboot`?

Comment: It could be. I can't speak with confidence. All I know is that `adb reboot` in my OnePlus 6 device doesn't do an instant shutdown the likes of which your device does. And adb shell reboot and adb reboot works the same in my device as well. In fact, I've never heard from anyone that adb shell reboot does a reboot the way your device does.

Comment: @Firelord https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002728/what-is-the-difference-between-the-abd-reboot-command-manually-pushing-the-power